# create ProducerTemplate for dynamic uri

Tags: java, apache-camel

Common ProducerTemplate usage is to declare a member and annotate with @Produce

```
@Produce(uri = "direct:start")
protected ProducerTemplate template;
```

and use as simple as

```
    String response = (String) template.requestBody(MESSAGE_BODY);
```

what if my uri is not known at compile time, how could I create ProducerTemplate?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean something like:

```
ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
template.requestBody("direct:start",MESSAGE_BODY);
```

Comment: Should I care about performance in this case? For example if I use netty uri, will it create connection each call?

Comment: I don't know your implementation details, but if you want to limit the max. open connections you can for example ensure that the code above is running not simultaneously.
Also reusing the ProducerTemplate itself is a good idea I think.

Comment: when you `context.createProducerTemplate()` it knows nothing about destination. This mean 'connection information' will be initialized on `requestBody("destination`, you can `requestBody("anotherDestination` and I think new 'connection' will be initialized for the second call. That is why I tend to think new connection are to be initialized for each request. And that would be horrible!

Answer (score 1):

When you send a message using the [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html), you can either rely on a default endpoint (specified in the annotation), or you can specify an endpoint directly.

So your example might look like:

```java
String response = template.requestBody("direct:start", MESSAGE_BODY, String.class);
```